# what to do so that I don't cut the string after the space

Tags: c++, string

I wrote a program that encrypts a string with the Caesar method. I have a problem when I try to enter a password consisting of several words separated by a space. the code itself works but cuts me off at the time of a space in the string

i tried to add some ifs but it didn't have any effect, so it only shows working code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    string wynik = "";
    int i,przesu;
    system("cls");
    cout << "how many shift a password" << endl;
    cin >> przesu;
    cout << "your password to encode: ";
    cin >> wynik;
    for (i = 0; i < wynik.length(); i++) {
         if ((int)wynik[i] == 32 ) {
              wynik[i] = wynik[i];
         }
         else {
            wynik[i] = toupper(wynik[i]);
          }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < wynik.length(); i++) {
        if (isupper(wynik[i])) {
            wynik[i] = wynik[i] + przesu;
            if (wynik[i] > 90) {
                wynik[i] = wynik[i] - 26;
            }
        }
        else {
                wynik[i] += wynik[i];
       }
        
    }
    cout << endl << "your encode password: " << wynik << endl;
    cout << "press any button to continue";
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) could be useful.

Comment: _However, cin considers a space (whitespace, tabs, etc) as a terminating character, which means that it can only display a single word (even if you type many words)_ [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_strings_input.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think that you could use the **getline()** function for this. It reads the line untill it encounters a delimiter(the end of line character "\n" by default). But you should also use **cin.ignore()** because without it your **getline()** function wouldn't work properly.

Here is your code with the **getline()**:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    string wynik = "";
    int i,przesu;
    system("cls");
    cout << "how many shift a password" << endl;
    cin >> przesu;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "your password to encode: ";
    getline(cin, wynik);
    for (i = 0; i < wynik.length(); i++) {
         if ((int)wynik[i] == 32 ) {
              wynik[i] = wynik[i];
         }
         else {
            wynik[i] = toupper(wynik[i]);
         }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < wynik.length(); i++) {
        if(wynik[i] != ' '){
            if (isupper(wynik[i])) {
                wynik[i] = wynik[i] + przesu;

                if (wynik[i] > 90) {
                    wynik[i] = wynik[i] - 26;
                }
            }
            else {
                wynik[i] += wynik[i];
            }
       }
    }
    cout << endl << "your encode password: " << wynik << endl;
    cout << "press any button to continue";
    _getch();
}
```

I also added another if statement in your second loop. It checks if the character is different than a space because we do not want any random symbols in our output. I hope that I answered your question. Let me know if you want to know anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string end_wynik = "",wynik;
    int i,przesu;
    system("cls");
    cout << "how many shift a password" << endl;
    cin >> przesu;
    cout << "your password to encode: ";
    while(cin >> wynik) {
        for (i = 0; i < wynik.length(); i++) {
            wynik[i] = toupper(wynik[i]);   
            if (isupper(wynik[i])) {
                wynik[i] = wynik[i] + przesu;
                if (wynik[i] > 90) {
                    wynik[i] = wynik[i] - 26;
                }
            }
            else {
                wynik[i] += wynik[i];
            }
        
        }
    end_wynik += wynik + " ";   
    }
    cout << endl << "your encode password: " << end_wynik << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Example here [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/G8rC8L)